# how can I get the position of the nonzero values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using np.nonzero() and i dont understand the return

I try

```
for groupPosition in np.nonzero(groupMatrix):
    print groupPosition
```

and return [0 0 1 2 3 3 3]

```
for groupPosition in zip(np.nonzero(groupMatrix)):
    print groupPosition
```

and return (array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3]),)

groupMatrix:

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  2.]
[ 3.  3.  0.  2.]]
```

But don't return the position like a (0, 0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> groupMatrix = np.array([
...     [1, 1, 0, 0],
...     [1, 0, 0, 0],
...     [0, 0, 0, 2],
...     [3, 3, 0, 2]
... ])
>>> np.nonzero(groupMatrix)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int64))
>>> zip(np.nonzero(groupMatrix))
[(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),), (array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)]
```

Use `zip(*...)`:

```
>>> zip(*np.nonzero(groupMatrix))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 3)]
```

---

`zip(*a)` is like `zip(a[0], a[1], ...)`

```
>>> a = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)]
>>> zip(a)
[((0, 1, 2),), ((3, 4, 5),)]
>>> zip(a[0], a[1])
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
>>> zip(*a)
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

See [`Unpacking Argument Lists`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

var = [
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0],
    [3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0]
]

rows, cols = np.nonzero(var)

for r, c in zip(rows, cols):
    print var[r][c]
```

Returns:

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
3.0
2.0
```

You are getting the results you are getting *because* `np.nonzero` returns a tuple, since your array has 2 dimensions, it has two arrays. Now, each of these arrays need to be used together, so in my example, the function returns the row number, and then the column number. Lets have a look see:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> var = [
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0],
    [3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0]
]
>>>                 
>>> non_zeroes = np.nonzero(var)
>>> non_zeroes
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3]))
```

If we take a close look, we can see that `var[0][0]` is indeed non zero. so is `var[3][3]`. However, you will not see a `2` in the first tuple and another `2` at the corresponding index.